# Duplicate Entry Warning Message Box

Tags: database, vba, ms-access-2007

I am trying to have a message box appear when a duplicate number is entered.  A duplicate in this table would be if BOTH fields match,  [Source] and [Voucher_Number].

[Source] is formatted as text

[Voucher_Number] is formatted as Number

Here is what my code looks like:

```
If (IsNull(DLookup("Source", "tblInvoiceLog", "Source ='" & 
Me.Source.Value & "'"))) And _
(IsNull(DLookup("Voucher_Number", "tblInvoiceLog", "Voucher_Number ='" &
Me.Voucher_Number.Value & "'"))) Then

Else
MsgBox "Duplicate Entery!" & Chr(13) & Chr(10) & "Please Use the Next
Available Consecutive Voucher Number", vbInformation, "Required"
End If

End Sub
```

I am getting:

> Run Time error 3464

What I would ultimately like to do, aside from solve this problem, is in the message box return the value of the field in the [Vendor_Name] for the original entry.

Thank you for any help anyone can lend

Comment: It's been a long time since I used VBA or VB, but it seems like you're intermixing & and "And" for logical operators... can you check to see if that code is correct?

Comment: Sorry the "Me.Source.Value & "'"))) And _ should read "Me.Source.Value & "'"))) OR _

Comment: Nevermind, I recall that the & is a string concat in VB... was confusing with the bitwise/logical operators of other languages. Seems like it would be better to concat your strings prior to the If statement though, at least that's the first thing I'd try.

Comment: What line is throwing the error?

Comment: (IsNull(DLookup("Voucher_Number", "tblInvoiceLog", "Voucher_Number ='" & Me.Voucher_Number.Value & "'"))) Then

Comment: & is a string concatenation. If that's your goal, do it in previous lines and then do the DLookup with that variable. If the & is supposed to be an "And", then that's likely your issue.

Comment: Ok, that gets me a runtime 13 error, Private Sub Voucher_Number_BeforeUpdate(Cancel As Integer)

If (IsNull(DLookup("Source", "tblInvoiceLog", "Source ='" & Me.Source.Value & "'"))) Or _
(IsNull(DLookup("Voucher_Number", "tblInvoiceLog", "Voucher_Number ='" And Me.Voucher_Number.Value & "'"))) Then
Else
MsgBox "Duplicate Entery!" & Chr(13) & Chr(10) & "Please Use the Next Available Consecutive Voucher Number", vbInformation, "Required"
End If

End Sub

Answer (score 1):

You could try casting the DLookup return values specifically as strings to ensure you are comparing apples to apples. If you still get an error, use F8 to step through it and hover over s1stLookup and s2ndLookup to see what values are assigned to the variables.

```
Dim s1stLookup as String
Dim s2ndLookup as String

'Specifically cast the DLookup return values as Strings
s1stLookup = CStr(DLookup("Source", "tblInvoiceLog", "Source ='" & Me.Source.Value & "'"))
s2ndLookup = CStr(DLookup("Voucher_Number", "tblInvoiceLog", "Voucher_Number ='" & Me.Voucher_Number.Value & "'"))

If (IsNull(s1stLookup)) And (IsNull(s2ndLookup)) Then
  '... Presumably some code here
Else
  MsgBox "Duplicate Entery!" & vbCrLF & _
    "Please Use the Next Available Consecutive Voucher Number", _
    vbInformation, "Required"
End If
```

Comment: Upvoted just for extracting the lookups out of the `If` statement; I would think `IsNull(String)` would return a consistent `False` regardless of the `DLookup` value, because of the `CStr`, so the condition could be rephrased as (if I'm not completely breaking this) `If Not (s1stLookup = vbNullString Or s2ndLookup = vbNullString) Then`, if there's only an `Else` branch. Also consider using `vbNewLine` instead of line feed + carriage return.

Comment: Run time error 3464, it looks like the first lookup is yielding an answer but the second is not?  I really do appreciate the time you are putting into this

Comment: First off, @Mat'sMug is correct. If DLookup returns Null, CStr will cast it as "1", so it will never be Null. Good catch Mat! If the 2nd DLookup is throwing a datatype mismatch error, try this: `"Voucher_Number =" & CStr(Me.Voucher_Number.Value)`

Comment: Ok I believe we are moving in the right direction, that yielded no run time errors, the problem is that it is not looking at both variables.  It sees that there is a [Voucher_Number] of X but not seeing if there is the combinations of [Source] AND [Voucher_Number] with X

Answer (score 0):

Currently you are testing for both values separately. But

> A duplicate in this table would be if BOTH fields match, [Source] and [Voucher_Number].

So you need to test if both values exist in the same record by putting both conditions with AND into the DLookup call. And since you want to get the `[Vendor_Name]` if it is a duplicate, you can directly lookup this field:

```
Dim sVendor as String
sVendor = Nz(DLookup("Vendor_Name", "tblInvoiceLog", _
    "Source = '" & Me.Source & "' AND Voucher_Number = " & Me.Voucher_Number), "")

If sVendor <> "" Then
    MsgBox "Duplicate entry of vendor '" & sVendor & "'."
Else
    ' ok, no dupe
End If
```

I find it's best to always use `Nz()` with `DLookup()` so I can work with strings instead of variants. An empty string means there was no result.

Comment: This worked perfectly, and much appreciated the tip.  Thank you so much